# Can't run web apps in new VS 2019 installation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

So, I downloaded an example solution (called mini-profiler) from GitHub which has a couple web apps in it. The solution runs in VS 2019. I had VS 2017 Enterprise, so I installed the latest VS 2019 (16.6.1). And I installed almost every single feature.

The web apps build fine. But when I try to run (debug or not) them I get...

[image]

This happens no matter which web app I try to run, or if I run it on IIS Express or IIS.

The guy who wrote mini-profiler didn't know what the problem was. And it doesn't look like the problem is specific to his library.

I can run stuff fine in my VS 2017 Enterprise (not this solution though, this solution won't load in VS 2017).

Also, another thing which I noticed is that the .NET Core frameworks are not available in the dropdown...

[image]

Even though I have a lot of them installed...

[image]

The web app project I was trying to run, "Samples.Mvc5" is not a .NET Core project, but still, I wanted to point that out.

FYI: The beginning of the csproj file looks like this...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>Samples.Mvc5</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>Samples.Mvc5</AssemblyName>
        <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
        <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
        <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

Here's what's installed in my VS 2019:

```
    "Component.Android.NDK.R16B",
    "Component.Android.SDK25.Private",
    "Component.Android.SDK28",
    "Component.Ant",
    "Component.CPython3.x64",
    "Component.Linux.CMake",
    "Component.MDD.Android",
    "Component.MDD.Linux",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.RazorExtension",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions",
    "Component.Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager",
    "Component.OpenJDK",
    "Component.Xamarin",
    "Component.Xamarin.RemotedSimulator",
    "Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools",
    "Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce",
    "Microsoft.Component.CodeAnalysis.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Native",
    "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools",
    "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools.Miniconda",
    "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools.Web",
    "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.SDK"
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites",
    "Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.TargetingPacks.Common",
    "Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK.2.2",
    "Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK.3.0",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.DevelopmentTools",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Web",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentTools.2.1",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web.2.1",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AspNet45",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.AuthoringTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ClientLibs",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Compute.Emulator",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Kubernetes.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Powershell",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ServiceFabric.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Storage.AzCopy",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Storage.Emulator",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton.BuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ClassDesigner",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DependencyValidation.Community",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DotNetModelBuilder",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.Desktop",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.WebTemplates",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.GraphDocument",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.LinqToSql",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSODBC.SQL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSSQL.CMDLnUtils",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Merq",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MonoDebugger",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Node.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.ADAL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Sharepoint.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TeamOffice",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.3.8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VSSDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Workflow",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.IISDevelopment",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.MSIX.Packaging",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Support",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtension.Prerequisites",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.TemplateEngine",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc4.ComponentGroup",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataScience",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeCrossPlat",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeMobile",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Python",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try restart your computeur? I add the same issue and restarting work for me. Some time visual studio is not working properly.

If this does work try vs-code, it free! Whit all the plugin, vs-code is good as a IDE!